# How does less know the terminal resolution?

Tags: terminal, less

Every time someone sets a different size for a virtual console, `less` recognizes the window resolution (I'm assuming that ...); according to that, it changes how many lines of text it should visualize. How is that parameter is computed?

Comment: Uhm ...ok, yet where I can find that procedure that's executed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to check from a script, you can do either of these:

- Run `tput cols` and `tput lines`, as manatwork suggests
- check the values of $LINES and $COLUMNS

But if you want the details, here we go:

For virtual terminals (xterm, et al) there is an `ioctl()` system call that will tell you what size the window is.  If it can, `less` uses this call.  Furthermore, when you change the size of the window, whatever's running in that window receives a `SIGWINCH` signal that lets `less` know that it should check for a new window size.  For instance, I started a `less` running (as process ID 16663), connected to it with `strace`, and resized the window.  This is what I saw:

```
$ strace -p 16663
Process 16663 attached - interrupt to quit
read(3, 0xbfb1f10f, 1)                  = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted)
--- SIGWINCH (Window changed) @ 0 (0) ---
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x805cf10, [WINCH], SA_RESTART}, {0x805cf10, [WINCH], SA_RESTART}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=40, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=40, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
```

This is also what `tput cols` and `tput lines` do behind the scenes, if they can.  For more info on this method, see `man tty-ioctl` and search for TIOCGWINSZ.

For other terminals such as those connected to serial ports, though, there's no way to get this info directly.  In that case, `less` starts looking for clues in the environment variables.

- `LINES` and `COLUMNS` will often be set to the terminal dimensions.  In fact, if `bash` or `zsh` can find the terminal dimensions, it will automatically set these variables itself, to make it easy for not-so-clever programs to see the terminal size.  However, most other shells, including `dash` and `tcsh`, do not set these variables.
- `TERM` is usually set to the terminal type, in which case the terminfo database may contain the expected size of the terminal.  If `tput rows` cannot use the IOCTL (for instance, if you're connected over a serial port), it will fall back to the values recorded here.  For a terminal whose size can change, this is only a guess and is likely to be wrong.

For more info, see `man tput` for the command to control the terminal, and `man terminfo` for a list of things you can tell the terminal to do.

Comment: The terminfo database doesn't do what was indicated here.  The answer by @warl0ck, which contains less information, is more accurate.

Comment: @ThomasDickey You're right; all it has is expected values.  Corrected my answer; thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at the source code, you will know `less` calls `ioctl()` to retrieve the window size on Linux.

```
#ifdef TIOCGWINSZ
    {
        struct winsize w;
        if (ioctl(2, TIOCGWINSZ, &w) == 0)
        {
            if (w.ws_row > 0)
                sys_height = w.ws_row;
            if (w.ws_col > 0)
                sys_width = w.ws_col;
        }
    }
#else
#ifdef WIOCGETD
    {
        struct uwdata w;
        if (ioctl(2, WIOCGETD, &w) == 0)
        {
            if (w.uw_height > 0)
                sys_height = w.uw_height / w.uw_vs;
            if (w.uw_width > 0)
                sys_width = w.uw_width / w.uw_hs;
        }
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the information that you are looking for. I guess `less` registers a signal handler for `SIGWINCH`. When the dimension of terminal changes, it gets a `SIGWINCH` signal and probe the tty information for current dimension of the terminal. 
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html